# How to build my ionic3 project for iOS

Tags: ionic3

I have a complete android app made in ionic3 , I have tested it in android (APK) and now I want to made the iOS app. I have my mac ready but I dont know how to export my app to my mac and then build it for iOS

Comment: Please see the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/#ios-devices)

Answer (score 0):

You **don't need a MAC**. You can use ionic's [**Package service**](https://docs.ionic.io/services/package/).

> Ionic Packages makes it easy to build a native binary of your app in
>   the cloud. Perfect for developers using Windows that want to build iOS
>   apps.

**This lets you:**

1. Send your packaged app to others
2. Build your app for platforms not supported by your computer (e.g.
   iOS builds on Windows)
3. Build `.ipa` and `.apk` files that you can submit to app stores